# grep stderr and stdout of previous command

Tags: bash, boolean, stdout, rhel, stderr

In bash script I need to check the stderr and stdout message of the command 1 and run command 2  if a string is found in message

Something like:

```
command 1

if [ $? != 0 ] and grep stderr and stdout of command 1 and if it contains hello world; then run

command 2

fi
```

Comment: Like `command1 |& grep -q "hello world" && command2` ?

Comment: @Spartan87 : You want to catch the output *after* the command has been executed??? Have you got a time machine to travel into the past? I suggest you simply collect the output in all cases, and if the exit code of command 1 is non-zero, grep what you have collected, otherwise throw it away.

Comment: @user1934428 - I think you misinterpreted the question. A command can produce output on both `stdout` and `stderr`, the question simply wants to consider both in a `grep` command to determine whether to run `command 2`, precisely what the preceding comment does.

Comment: Hmmmm, since the OP explicitly wrote in the example code "If $? of the previous command is non-zero, THEN grep the output of command 1". I just took his posting at face-value. Why do you think he meant otherwise?

Comment: @Spartan87 : As you can see from this discussion, it would help if you would write more precisely what you are going to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect the output of command1 to a file and then use grep to check if the files contains the string 'hello world'

```
command1 > /tmp/stdout.$$ 2>/tmp/stderr.$$
if [ $? -ne 0 ] && grep 'hello world' /tmp/stdout.$$ /tmp/stderr; then
    command2;
fi
```

You could also combine into a single file using the "2>&1" syntax (redirect file descriptor 2 (stderr) to file descriptor 1 (stdout).

```
command1 > /tmp/stdout-stderr.$$ 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ] && grep 'hello world' /tmp/stdout-stderr.$$; then
    command2;
fi
```